# Titanium Google Authentication

Tags: oauth, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, google-authentication

I've been using https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium to login users with their Gmail accounts, but on April 2017 Google will start to block login from web views on mobile devices.

I've created this issue on the repo with more information: https://github.com/ejci/Google-Auth-for-Titanium/issues/13.

This blog post https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html explains that we must use a native way of doing so.

Does anyone know of a module for Titanium (iOS and Android) where we can log users with their Gmail accounts?

Thank you so much

Comment: Hans already did a iOS module: https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.googlesignin
Let's see if someone starts the Android one =)

Comment: An Android version is available here: https://github.com/AppWerft/Ti.GoogleSignIn

Comment: Did you get valid token from above mentioned android module in order to access any google api e.g. google drive. I am using this module and using the token from login response but getting invalid credentials error 401 ... On the other hand if i uses the token from google developer playground, i could access the google drive without any problem